# Error : InvalidClientTokenId and The security token included in the request is invalid in postman (sp-api)

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, sts, amazonsellercentral

I,m trying to connect postman with amazon seller central to request for the api.
i have checked multiple time but the access key and security key is right. but i don't know why this problem is occuring?

`

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
   <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code>
    <Message>The security token included in the request is invalid.</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>056c7861-815a-4c19-a52a-9fac0f280588</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

`

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpePM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGTfa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxk8N.png)